# Pausing Python asyncio coroutines

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

As my project heavily relies on asynchronous network I/O, I always have to expect some weird network error to occur: whether it is the service I'm connecting to having an API outage, or my own server having a network issue, or something else. Issues like that appear, and there's no real way around it. So, I eventually ended up trying to figure out a way to effectively "pause" a coroutine's execution from outside whenever such a network issue occured, until the connection has been reestablished. My approach is writing a decorator `pausable` that takes an argument `pause` which is a coroutine function that will be `yield`ed `from` / `await`ed like this:

```
def pausable(pause, resume_check=None, delay_start=None):
    if not asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(pause):
        raise TypeError("pause must be a coroutine function")
    if not (delay_start is None or asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(delay_start)):
        raise TypeError("delay_start must be a coroutine function")

    def wrapper(coro):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if delay_start is not None:
                yield from delay_start()
            for x in coro(*args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    yield from pause()
                    yield x
                # catch exceptions the regular discord.py user might not catch
                except (asyncio.CancelledError,
                        aiohttp.ClientError,
                        websockets.WebSocketProtocolError,
                        ConnectionClosed,
                        # bunch of other network errors
                        ) as ex:
                    if any((resume_check() if resume_check is not None else False and
                            isinstance(ex, asyncio.CancelledError),
                            # clean disconnect
                            isinstance(ex, ConnectionClosed) and ex.code == 1000,
                            # connection issue
                            not isinstance(ex, ConnectionClosed))):
                        yield from pause()
                        yield x
                    else:
                        raise

        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

Pay special attention to this bit:

```
for x in coro(*args, **kwargs):
    yield from pause()
    yield x
```

Example usage (`ready` is an `asyncio.Event`):

```
@pausable(ready.wait, resume_check=restarting_enabled, delay_start=ready.wait)
@asyncio.coroutine
def send_test_every_minute():
    while True:
        yield from client.send("Test")
        yield from asyncio.sleep(60)
```

However, this does not seem to work and it does not seem like an elegant solution to me. Is there a working solution that is compatible with Python 3.5.3 and above? Compatibility with Python 3.4.4 and above is desirable.

#### Addendum

Just `try`/`except`ing the exceptions raised in the coroutine that needs to be paused is neither always possible nor a viable option to me as it heavily violates against a core code design principle (DRY) I'd like to comply with; in other words, excepting so many exceptions in so many coroutine functions would make my code messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few words about current solution.

```
for x in coro(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        yield from pause()
        yield x
    except
        ...
```

You won't be able to catch exceptions this way:

- exception raises outside of for-loop
- generator is exhausted (not usable) after first exception anyway

.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def test():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    raise RuntimeError()
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('ok')



@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    coro = test()
    try:
        for x in coro:
            try:
                yield x
            except Exception:
                print('Exception is NOT here.')
    except Exception:
        print('Exception is here.')

        try:
            next(coro)
        except StopIteration:
            print('And after first exception generator is exhausted.')


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Output:

```
Exception is here.
And after first exception generator is exhausted.
```

Even if it was possible to resume, consider what will happen if coroutine already did some cleanup operations due to exception.

---

Given all above, if some coroutine raised exception only option you have is to suppress this exception (if you want) and re-run this coroutine. You can rerun it after some event if you want. Something like this:

```
def restart(ready_to_restart):
    def wrapper(func):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            while True:
                try:
                    return (yield from func(*args, **kwargs))
                except (ConnectionClosed,
                        aiohttp.ClientError,
                        websockets.WebSocketProtocolError,
                        ConnectionClosed,
                        # bunch of other network errors
                        ) as ex:
                    yield from ready_to_restart.wait()


ready_to_restart = asyncio.Event()  # set it when you sure network is fine 
                                    # and you're ready to restart
```

---

**Upd**

> However, how would I make the coroutine continue where it was
>   interrupted now?

Just to make things clear:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def test():
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        yield from client.request_1()
        # STEP 1:
        # Let's say line above raises error

        # STEP 2:
        # Imagine you you somehow maged to return to this place
        # after exception above to resume execution.
        # But what is state of 'client' now?
        # It's was freed by context manager when we left coroutine.
        yield from client.request_2()
```

Nor functions, nor coroutines are designed to resume their execution after exception was propagated outside from them.

Only thing that comes to mind is to split complex operation to re-startable little ones while whole complex operation can store it's state:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def complex_operation():
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        res = yield from step_1(client)

        # res/client - is a state of complex_operation.
        # It can be used by re-startable steps.

        res = yield from step_2(client, res)


@restart(ready_to_restart)
@asyncio.coroutine
def step_1():
    # ...


@restart(ready_to_restart)
@asyncio.coroutine
def step_2():
    # ...
```

Comment: I really like this approach, and thanks for your great answer! However, how would I make the coroutine continue where it was interrupted now? I thought about passing it a dict called `state` in which the coroutine would have to store its variables in and retrieve its variables from at the beginning. [Example implementation](https://github.com/AileenLumina/discord.py/blame/ae84da45c6d49f88218f974aa2658c40bb0994b1/discord/client.py#L821-L832)